# Gatling : session.isFailed returning true even the previously executed request has succeeded

Tags: performance, gatling, scala-gatling

I was tasked with running some performance tests in order to benchmark our systems. I designed the scenario as below :

```
var scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Sample Scenario")
    .exec(
      forever(
        exec(<first request>)
          .pause(2, 5)
          .doIf(session => !session.isFailed) {
            randomSwitch(
              70d -> exec(<second request>),
              15d -> exec(<third request),
              15d -> exec(<fourth request>)
            )
          }
      )
    )
```

The issue I'm facing cropped up when we were performing fail-over tests in our system. I noticed that during the simulation all of requests stopped executing after the "first request" once a failure was introduced in the system.

I checked the logs and the "first request" was successful and as per my understanding `!session.isFailed` condition should be true allowing for further execution of the scenario.

Can anyone please share why the condition is being marked as `false` instead of `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Gatling.io team:

---

The session keeps its status even after several requests.

As you mentioned, `a failure was introduced in the system`

One of the primary goals is to have points in your scenario where the virtual user may leave (because of the failure) with `exitHereIfFailed`

If you want to recover, you should mark your session as succeeded.

```
var scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Sample Scenario")
    .exec(
      forever(
        exec(session => session.markAsSucceeded) // <---- reset the status
          .exec(<first request>)
          .pause(2, 5)
          .doIf(session => !session.isFailed) {
            randomSwitch(
              70d -> exec(<second request>),
              15d -> exec(<third request),
              15d -> exec(<fourth request>)
            )
          }
      )
    )
```